# Difference in random forest probabilities in r

Tags: random-forest

I have built random forest model and saved the model. There are few numeric variables and few hot coded and converted as factor variables.

I have a situation where some of the records in new data are also part of the train data and the prediction probabilities are differing for the similar records.
Saved model name is Rfmod.

Used the following code run the predictions:

```
load(Rfmod) 
Pred <- predict(Rfmod, newdata, type ='prob')
```

The probabilities for the common records in both train and new data is not same. Any thoughts on this? I have also tried passing newdata option in predict function, but the difference is still there.

Comment: are the records exactly the same or just similar?

Comment: Hi Davide DN, Those records are exactly same and still the probabilities are different.